# iOS - Constantly update a method

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an application with BLE and am trying to constantly scan every known device to get there most up to date RSSI(for judging distance).  I've looked into implementing a timer, but I'm not sure if this is the best/only way to do it.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: A timer is probably the best way to do it. It doesn't take much memory and is very easy to start/stop.

Comment: Cool I'll stick with the timer then, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSTimer seems to do the trick.  Heres a good tutorial:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/23/nstimer-the-poor-mans-threading-code-snapshot/

Answer (score 1):

Like fatshu said:

```
[peripheral readRSSI];
rssiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RSSI : %d",[peripheral.RSSI integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution. You should use CBPeripheral and its delegate CBPeripheralDelegate to get notified for RSSI changes on the peripheral device. Scanning is one of the most costly operations.